# Google Maps Android API, Enable Blue Lines in Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

Google recently added [blue lines](http://9to5google.com/2016/06/08/google-maps-street-view-ui/) to ease navigation in Street Views accessed through the Google Maps App.  Can these blue lines be enabled via the Google Maps Android API as well?

I Googled but there is too much noise about blue lines in different contexts.